# Are min_price and max_price in catalog_product_index_price accurate for products with tiered pricing?

Tags: price, simple-product, tiered-pricing

It seems like `min_price` and `max_price` aren't generally accurate in `catalog_product_index_price` for simple products using tiered pricing.

I haven't yet drilled into `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default` to get a better idea of what's going on under the hood, but I've taken a look at the sample data.

Here's a product using tiered pricing:

[image: simple product with tiered pricing]

And the values in `catalog_product_index_price` for it:

[image: index values for simple product with tiered pricing]

I would think this would be a perfect place for `min_price` to reflect, well, the minimum possible price for the product.  It does seem that the `tier_price` column perhaps contains that value though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at SELECT of Magento Product Collection, you'll see that Magento does `LEAST(min_price, tier_price, group_price) as minimal_price`.

So you minimal_price is not a value from min_price column. I think it is done, to make a lowest possible price without group or tier price discounts being available for devs to access. Especially if you consider all that backward compatibility mess.